# Comparing 2 lists using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists I am trying to compare. I execute the following and I get a `false` value returned:

```
var areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, myFileCompare);
```

That part is working. My lists are NOT equal. The problem is, I'm using the following command to try to find the differences:

```
var fileDiff = (from file in list1 
                select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare);
```

My problem is, `fileDiff` is returning an empty result set. Since I know they are NOT identical, shouldn't I get something returned? Perhaps my query is wrong on this. Any help would be appreciated! By the way, I can post more of my code, if you really need it, however, this should suffice.

Comment: What kind of difference are we talking about here? Ordering? Object cont?

Comment: Can you give us the contents of list1 and list2?

Comment: What type of object is in your lists?  Are you sure the default comparer is doing what you think its?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't get anything if:

- `list2` contained everything in `list1` but also extra items
- the ordering was different

Assuming you don't care about the ordering, you can use:

```
var extraItemsInList2 = list2.Except(list1);
var extraItemsInList1 = list1.Except(list2);
```

If you *do* care about the order, you'll need to work out *exactly* how you want the differences to be represented.

Comment: I don't really care about the order. What I'm doing is comparing files in a directory. `list1` is file contents of directory one and `list2` is file contents of directory two. I am using [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx) for reference.

Comment: @icemanind: Right, in that case the code I gave you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`SequenceEqual()` will return true only if the elements as well as the element sequence is the same.

`Except()` will compare only the elements, not the sequence.

Your two lists obviously have different sequences but, judging by the behavior you've posted, I'm guessing they both contain the same elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) (all differences between either list, ordering is not important) then you could use the following which will be heavy on the computation but should do the trick:

```
var fileDiff = list1.Union(list2).Except(list1.Intersect(list2));
```

Or (as per [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665963/comparing-2-lists-using-linq/7666003#7666003)):

```
var fileDiff = list1.Except(list2).Union(list2.Except(list1));
```

I'll leave it to the rest of the community to show you a more efficient way to do it... But this is the most obvious "linq" way that I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

`SequenceEqual` cares about sequence (which is kind of hinted in its name ;) ), but `Except` doesn't.

- So it is entirely possible that `list2` contains same elements as `list1`, **but in different order**, so `SequenceEqual` returns `false` yet `Except` returns no elements.
- It is also possible that `list2` is a proper super-set of the `list1`, in which case `SequenceEqual` returns `false` regardless of order, and `Except` still returns no elements.

If you want to work with set operations, you'll probably be better off using some set-like container such as `HashSet` or `SortedSet` directly. In your case, you might be interested in `HashSet.SetEquals` and/or `HashSet.ExceptWith`.